# Stop loss and take profit system is very broken

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

In my system the stop loss is place at the lowest low of price in last five candles but if the distance between that an the price is less than 0.075% than a minimum stop loss distance is used. Same for shorts but flipped.

```
MinStopLong = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - 0.00075)
MinStopShort = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + 0.00075)
StopLossLong = ta.lowest(low,5)
StopLossShort = ta.highest(high,5)
if MinStopLong < StopLossLong
    StopLossLong := MinStopLong
if MinStopShort > StopLossShort
    StopLossShort := MinStopShort

//Take Profit

TakeProfitLong = strategy.position_avg_price + (2 * (strategy.position_avg_price - StopLossLong))
TakeProfitShort = strategy.position_avg_price - (2 *(StopLossShort - strategy.position_avg_price))

//Plot

//Strategy Exit
if strategy.position_avg_price>0
    strategy.exit(id='loss', stop=StopLossLong) 
    strategy.exit(id='win',limit=TakeProfitLong)
if strategy.position_avg_price<0
    strategy.exit(id='loss', stop=StopLossShort)
    strategy.exit(id='win', limit=TakeProfitShort)'''
```

Buys seem to not be taking profits and shorts seem to be taking a loss in the next open. I have no clue as to why this is breaking this badly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use 1 strategy.exit only, you don't need 2
I feel that's the main issue, the first strategy.exit is set to exit 100% of the trade, and then the second strategy.exit can't have anything left to exit

Comment: Its a take profit and stop loss system what do you mean i dont need two?

Answer (score 0):

I meant, use 1 only strategy.exit handling both your SL and TP

Comment: oh ill try that I thought you meant get rid of a take profit or something like that